# Comparing velocities of two distinct parametrizations of the same curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, parametrization

I have two positive functions $f(t,a),g(t,a)$ related by an ODE system of form
$$\dfrac{df}{dt}=F_1(f(t,a),g(t,a),a),\\
\dfrac{dg}{dt}=F_2(f(t,a),g(t,a),a),$$

where $a$ is a parameter.

I know that for all fixed $a$ I have the same curve $\mathcal{C}$ for the parametrization $(f(t,a),g(t,a))$ for $t\in(0,\infty)$, I mean, I have the same phase-plane.

I'd like to prove that the velocity in which the curve $\mathcal{C}$ is traveled is greater for $a$ bigger.

However, the calculations are not possible to be explicited.

I know that, given positive fixed functions $p,q$, I have $F(p(t,a),q(t,a),a)>F(p(t,b),q(t,b),b)$ for all time $t$, in each coordinate, if $a>b$.

Thank you so much for any suggestion to procedure.

====================================

A very simple example.

$$\dfrac{df}{dt}=a/f(t),\\
\dfrac{dg}{dt}=a,$$

We see that $dg/df$ is invariant for $a$, so the curve $(f,g)$ is invariant for $a$.

The velocity squared is $a^2\dfrac{f^2+1}{f^2}$. How can I calculate the derivative wrt $a$ to see how the velocities of the parametrizations change if $f$ is also related with $a$? (In this case, the system can be solved explicitly, but I am seeking a general procedure!)

Comment: I haven't worked out the answer, but wouldn't the first step be to write down the formula for the magnitude of the velocity? And see what happens if you differentiate it?

Comment: @Deane, yes, this is the problem, the functions are special functions that we could not differentiate easily

Comment: The velocity of the curve is $v(t,a) = (f_t(t,a),g_t(t,a))$ and therefore its magnitude squared is $|v|^2 = (f_t)^2 + (g_t)^2$. Now the question is whether the derivative of this with respect to $a$ is positive. Have you done this calculation (without using any specific formula for $F, G, f, g$)?

Comment: Well, so derivating $|v|^2$ wrt $a$, I think we have $2(f_tf_{ta}+g_tg_{ta})$, which is $2FF_a^T$. From my condition, I have $F_a>0$ (is it correct)? I know that $F_1<0$, but $F_2$ can change the signal... Am I following the right path? Thank you so much!

Comment: To be honest, I don’t know the answer, so I don’t know the right path. But you’re doing what I would do. See what you can infer from the equations. If you’re not able to prove what you want, see if you can come up with a counterexample. Keep at it.

Comment: @Deane, I'll translate the problem into a much simpler, could you please take a new look at the question? Thank you so much

Comment: I see better your difficulty. You should make explicit the fact that $f$ and $g$ depend not only on $t$ but also on $a$. So I would write $f(t,a)$ and $g(t,a)$ instead of just $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. And then maybe you need to use the equations you get by differentiating the original system with respect to $a$. Just a guess.